# Code snippet plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, code-snippets

Are there any good code snippet plugins for visual studio? I want a plugin which can use a online snippet site (such as [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/)). It should be easy to both find and upload snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes [CodeKeep](http://www.codekeep.net/)

Answer (score 5):

You might consider [snip2code](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7eb92b2f-2637-4772-a231-96bce8790171) plugin for VS2010.
It's interesting, I got it online... 
Allows to search for your own snippets and public as well. Quick collector of code.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://www.int64.io.

It allows you to store snippets online. You can organize your snippets into "boards", give them tags, search (in near future), etc. It doesn't have a Visual Studio plugin yet, but it's coming.

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of http://www.int64.io

Answer (score 0):

You might consider http://code.google.com/p/cr-codetweet/